# volume of a regular hexagon pyramid.

Tags: volume

The length of the altitude $h$ of a regular hexagon pyramid is three times the length of the side $s$ of the base. What is the volume of the pyramid in terms of $h$?

Comment: What have you tried? Please show some effort by showing your steps and being clear on what you're stuck on.

Comment: @TobyMak h=3s then the regular hexagon pyramid affected if the side of the base is 1/3 of the altitude of the pyramid..so we will derive this formula ...

Comment: You can put that in your question. Don't worry about the downvotes - since many questions are just posted here with no effort, people tend to downvote them because it *looks like* you haven't shown any.

Comment: @TobyMak ok ..in my solution it's take something wrong in my final answer..wait I'll take a picture..

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

Remember the formula for a pyramid is $\frac{1}{3} * a * h$. Since we know that $h=3s$, then we have $a * \frac{1}{3} * 3s$, or $as$, where $a$ is the base area, $h$ is the height of the pyramid, and $s$ is the side length of the base.

Now to find the base area, split the hexagon up into $6$ smaller equilateral triangles. You can either use the Pythagorean theorem or trigonometry to calculate the area of one of them. Put this in terms of $h$ and simplify the expression.